# How can I use string interpolation while iterating over a dictionary in python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, string-interpolation

I have a dictionary full of states and their abbreviations mapped to their actual names. And I want to iterate over them, because I want to make a task easier (don't want to write this out for each state). So far I have a dictionary like this

```
state_dict = {
    'AK': 'ALASKA',
    'AL': 'ALABAMA',
    'AR': 'ARKANSAS',
    'AS': 'AMERICAN SAMOA',
    'AZ': 'ARIZONA ',
    'CA': 'CALIFORNIA ',
    'CO': 'COLORADO ',
    'CT': 'CONNECTICUT',
    'DC': 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA',
    'DE': 'DELAWARE',
    'FL': 'FLORIDA',
    'FM': 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA',
    'GA': 'GEORGIA',
    'GU': 'GUAM ',
    'HI': 'HAWAII',
    'IA': 'IOWA',
    'ID': 'IDAHO',
    'IL': 'ILLINOIS',
    'IN': 'INDIANA',
    'KS': 'KANSAS',
    'KY': 'KENTUCKY',
    'LA': 'LOUISIANA',
    'MA': 'MASSACHUSETTS',
    'MD': 'MARYLAND',
    'ME': 'MAINE',
    'MH': 'MARSHALL ISLANDS',
    'MI': 'MICHIGAN',
    'MN': 'MINNESOTA',
    'MO': 'MISSOURI',
    'MP': 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS',
    'MS': 'MISSISSIPPI',
    'MT': 'MONTANA',
    'NC': 'NORTH CAROLINA',
    'ND': 'NORTH DAKOTA',
    'NE': 'NEBRASKA',
    'NH': 'NEW HAMPSHIRE',
    'NJ': 'NEW JERSEY',
    'NM': 'NEW MEXICO',
    'NV': 'NEVADA',
    'NY': 'NEW YORK',
    'OH': 'OHIO',
    'OK': 'OKLAHOMA',
    'OR': 'OREGON',
    'PA': 'PENNSYLVANIA',
    'PR': 'PUERTO RICO',
    'RI': 'RHODE ISLAND',
    'SC': 'SOUTH CAROLINA',
    'SD': 'SOUTH DAKOTA',
    'TN': 'TENNESSEE',
    'TX': 'TEXAS',
    'UT': 'UTAH',
    'VA': 'VIRGINIA ',
    'VI': 'VIRGIN ISLANDS',
    'VT': 'VERMONT',
    'WA': 'WASHINGTON',
    'WI': 'WISCONSIN',
    'WV': 'WEST VIRGINIA',
    'WY': 'WYOMING'
}
```

---

```
for k, v in state_dict.items():
    print("""if (c_state_code.equals("{k}"))
               {
                   out_state_code = "{v}";
               }""").format(k, v)
```

But I'm getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format, and I even tried **attrs in the .format but got the same error.

Comment: Because `print` returns `None` and you are calling `print(...).format(k,v)`

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but it looks like you are attempting to use a python dict to generate code in another language (Java? C#?). This begs the question: Why don't you use an equivalent mapping (ie a HashMap) in that language?

Comment: yeah I'm using Python to create code in Java, because I didn't feel like typing it all out, and I'm not at all comfortable with Java, Python is my main langauage.

Comment: @Alex well, having 51 `if` branches is quite a mess instead of using a Java HashMap (which is not very difficult to learn), but to each their own I guess :)

Comment: I'll have to take a dive into hashmap, thanks for the advice, yeah this is quite a lot of if statements, so yeah you may have a point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `format()` on the result of `print()`, which doesn't return anything. It should be called on the format string -- it needs to be inside the argument to `print()`.

```
for k, v in state_dict.items():
   print("""if (c_state_code.equals("{k}"))
              {{
                  out_state_code = "{v}";
              }}""".format(k, v))
```

If you're using Python version 3.6 you can make it even easier using an f-string.

```
for k, v in state_dict.items():
   print(f"""if (c_state_code.equals("{k}"))
              {{
                  out_state_code = "{v}";
              }}""")
```

Comment: geez I can't believe I put the .format in the wrong place, nice catch, I guess it's a Monday! Thanks for the heads up on the f-strings, I haven't used those before but they seem like it could be nifty!

Comment: You forgot to change the `out_state_code` variable into an `f-string`!!!

Comment: @AyushGarg The syntax highlighting was acting funny becuse the braces should be `{{` and `}}`. I fixed that.

Comment: @megargayu It's inside the original f-string, it doesn't need to be changed. The output of this is not Python.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, right - I think it was just the syntax highlighting (pointed out by @DeepSpace)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this code, I think [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973466/11483682) is pretty good. However, it looks like you are trying to copy and paste a million different if statements to convert the initials of a state  into the state name. In this case, I would use the dictionary (or even store it in a `JSON` file!)

```
state_dict = {...}
out_state_code = state_dict[c_state_code]
```

*or*

```
import json
with open("states.json", "r") as states_file:
    state_dict = json.load(states_file)
out_state_code = state_dict[c_state_code]
```

Comment: It looks like he's using Python to write a program in some other language.

Comment: Ya, I figured - this is just supposed to be an example in python @Barmar